# Twitter API oAuth (Error code 214: Bad authentication data)

Tags: c#, api, twitter, oauth, dynamics-crm-2011

I am close to getting this to work with Microsoft Dynamics CRM application, However, I get Error code 214: Bad authentication data.:(

The request URL is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=aspas10&since_id=342379690448805888

> Authentication Header: OAuth oauth_nonce=”**********”,
>   oauth_signature_method=”HMAC-SHA1″, oauth_timestamp=”1372370208″,
>   oauth_consumer_key=”*************”,
>   oauth_token=”**********************”,
>   oauth_signature=”****************”, oauth_version=”1.0″

My code includes:

```
request.Headers.Add(“Authorization”, authHeader);
request.Method = “GET”;
request.ContentType = “application/x-www-form-urlencoded”;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
return response;
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong and why I am getting this error?

Comment: You're getting it because the authentication data is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the code of how are you getting the authHeader? I think the problem is there.

Also have a look at this example and make sure you have the same headers:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Twitter-OAuth-Example-3a99967f

Regards,

Mario

PS: Maybe is my proxy, but I can't navigate to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=aspas10&since_id=342379690448805888

Comment: Hi Mario. It is exactly the same code you have written. :) Seems that the Twitter API v1 Retirement on 11th June messed up the plugin. I have changed the url from https://api.twitter.com/1.0/ to  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/ and the url to use .json instead of .xml.... Any help will be appreciated. ;)